# Change the order of tuple fields

Tags: apache-pig

As an example, lets say I load two different files into a pig script

```
A = LOAD 'file1' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (
    day:chararray,
    month:chararray,
    year:chararray,
    message:chararray);

B = LOAD 'file2' USING PigStorage('\t) AS (
    month:chararray,
    day:chararray,
    year:chararry,
    message:chararray);
```

Now, notice the order of the fields is different, so if I combine them into one file `C = UNION A, B;` I get...

```
(2,OCT,2013,INFO INVALID USERNAME)
(OCT,3,2013,WARN STACK OVERFLOW)
```

If for no other reason than to make the data easier to read, I'd like to reorder the fields, so that both of them follow a common format and have the same positional notation for each field.

```
(2,OCT,2013,INFO INVALID USERNAME)
(3,OCT,2013,WARN STACK OVERFLOW)
```

This also crops up in a few other places with messages, levels, hosts, etc. It's not just date fields, I'd like to make everything "prettier" all around.

In some weird pseudo-code, I'd be looking for something like:

```
D = FOREACH B
    REORDER (month,day,year) TO (day,month,year);
```

I haven't been able to find an example of anyone trying to do this and don't see a function that would do it. So maybe it's not possible and I'm alone here, but if anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is not necessary in Pig because you can just refer to fields by name and not worry about their position in the record.  If your goal is to do a `UNION` of the two relations, you can achieve this by using the `ONSCHEMA` keyword:

```
C = UNION ONSCHEMA A, B;
```

That said, if you do really need to reorder a relation, a simple `FOREACH...GENERATE` is all you need:

```
D = FOREACH B GENERATE day, month, year, message;
```

Note that in your example, you are not actually working with tuples, you are working with entire records.  If you did have a tuple, though, you can use the `TOTUPLE` built-in UDF to get where you need to go:

```
DESCRIBE E;
E: {t: (month: chararray,day: chararray,year: chararray,message: chararray)}

F = FOREACH E GENERATE TOTUPLE(t.day, t.month, t.year, t.message) AS t;
DESCRIBE F;
F: {t: (day: chararray,month: chararray,year: chararray,message: chararray)}
```

Comment: GENERATE is exactly what I was looking for. ONSCHEMA works even better though since it will leave null fields if I don't have data in one file. Perfect, thanks! One followup question for my own education though. A Tuple is "an ordered set of fields" and a field is "a piece of data". So how is each line not a tuple? Aren't {} brackets used to describe a bag? Here's the reference I'm looking at. https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#relations

Comment: Yes, you are correct that technically a relation is stored as a bag of tuples, with each record being a tuple.  However, this could be confusing for some as you can also have a tuple as one of the fields.  In the latter case, you would need to use the `TOTUPLE` function as indicated.